# Duvidas SQL - duas tabelas (planilhas excel) consolidadas

Tags: sql

Olá.
Estou com uma duvida, que creio ser simples para os veteranos do forum.
Não tenho muita noção de SQL, mas preciso integrar dois arquivos em excel
Um de estoque e um de vendas

São dois xls diferentes. Os dois possuem um BD (aba) chamada "Base Geral".

Tenho colunas de marca, produto, mês, ano e valores... onde:

Na planilha de estoque , o meu campo de valor se chama ESTOQUE e na de vendas, VENDA

Preciso criar uma terceira planilha que consolide as duas via Query, onde eu levarei as colunas de (MARCA / PRODUTO / ANO / MES) das duas e levarei a ESTOQUE e VENDAS tambem, além de criar uma terceira coluna..
Nessa terceira coluna, chamada "SAIDA ESTOQUE", a formula é a seguinte:

```
SAIDA ESTOQUE = Estoque do mês anterior* + venda - estoque do mês atual
```

Desta forma, no estoque do mes anterior, precisaria fazer um prov ou somase, puxando o valor do mes anterior... por exemplo. se eu trouxer uma linha que tenha mes de fevereiro, deve trazer    (ESTOQUE DE JANEIRO + vendas de fevereiro - Estoque de fevereiro)

Se alguém me ajudar a resolver, agradeço imensamente.
PS: já usei union no sql, mas empaquei nas colunas com nomes diferentes

[![imagem 1 - base de estoque][1]][1]

[![imagem 2 - base de vendas][2]][2]

[image: imagem 3 - esta seria a planilha final.. onde eu conseguiria agrupar os dados da base de Estoque e de vendas]

infelizmente não consigo inserir todas as imagens

Comment: seria util colocar  algum codigo para podermos verificar apenas palavras é dificil ver o seu real problema, caso tenha leia https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Você está importando os `xls` para alguma tabela e quer unir os dados com `SQL`? É isso?

Comment: na verdade não Marcelo... eu estou jogando os dois arquivos de excel diretamente para um outro arquivo em excel... em (Dados > de outras fontes >Microsoft Query > arquivos excel).... o que eu queria era unir essa consulta de forma automática.. desta forma, toda vez que as duas "bases" fossem atualizadas.. quando eu atualizasse esta consulta, eu conseguisse replicar o que pretendo para a tabela

Answer (score 1):

Pode fazer da seguinte forma:

Passo 1: Criar consulta para o arquivo 1 (Imagem 1)

Passo 2: Criar consulta para o arquivo 2 (Imagem 1)

Passo 3: Criar uma nova consulta Pelo menu "Combinar Consultas" > "Iniciar Editor de consultas" (Imagem 2)

Passo 4: Manter as colunas desejadas de cada consulta, se necessário, pode clicar com o botão direito para renomear as colunas.

[image: Imagem 1]

[image: Imagem 2]

Comment: boa tarde Alexandre.. na verdade, eu não queria subir os dados como tabela. eu tenho dois arquivos em excel, relativamente pesados... o que gostaria de fazer é ter um novo excel, onde eu possa atualizar a tabela de dados e conseguir disponibilizar as informações de forma automática... eu nunca subi dados de consulta, utilizando duas tabelas... geralmente, faço isso usando um único arquivo.. e só para fim de consulta mesmo.... desta vez, queria integrar os dois arquivos e incluir algumas operações no arquivo que vai consolidar as duas tabelas... não sei se isto realmente é possivel

Comment: Entendi, isso também poderia ser feito no SQL e depois transportar para o Excel. Mas editei a resposta para utilização das consultas diretamente no Excel.

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda.... o problema é que não sei se isso esta disponível no Excel 2010. Eu até consegui fazer a integração usando right outer join... e inner join.... o problema é que eu precisaria de uma consulta completa que tivesse todos os valores.. mas ta dando erro quando eu tento aplicar Full outer join.. eu cheguei a postar o exemplo num outro fórum onde eu consigo anexar arquivos... isso é temporário.. é que precisava consolidar uma base aqui.. vou tentar me matricular num curso de banco de dados o mais rápido possivel

Comment: O Stack Overflow não é um fórum.